# How can I autofill alphabetical characters from AAA to ZZZ in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

So if I type in the following data:

[image: A row of cells from AAA to AAC]

I want to be able to drag the handle in the bottom right to expand the list all the way to ZZZ if necessary. By default, excel just repeats the sequence I typed.

Comment: There are not enough columns to make it all the way to ZZZ.  There are 17576 combinations and only 16384 columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your data to rows instead of columns, there are not enough columns to get to ZZZ.

```
=CHAR(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/26^2)+65)&CHAR(MOD(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/26),26)+65)&CHAR(MOD((ROW(1:1)-1),26)+65)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Excellent and robust. I think you can just use `ROW()` without an argument and it will assume the current cell.

Comment: @EngineerToast yes, but that assumes that the OP will put it in row 1.  This way if another comes later and wants to start in row 2 it will not start at `AAB`

Comment: Good point. Your answer is certainly better.

Comment: Thanks. How did you collapse the rows like that, by the way?

Comment: "Freeze panes", I assume.

Comment: @Tharwen  I hid the other rows.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have Excel 2007 or later, start in column A with the formula:

```
=MID(ADDRESS(1,702+COLUMN()),2,3)
```

This just takes advantage of the fact that column 703 is `AAA`. If you start in a different column, adjust the value of `702` as needed.

Comment: This will only go to `XFD` before throwing errors.

Comment: @ScottCraner That's true but, as you pointed out above, you can only get to `YGD` (I think) before it breaks on any method using `Address`.

Comment: using Address it will only go to `XFD` as there are no more columns beyond that.  There is no column `XFE` so it will be an error `#Value` after that. Everything after column WED will be an error.

Comment: If you append `AA` to the left of the address and return the 3 right characters, you can start with column `A` and, thus, get 702 addresses further which I think is `YGD`. It's still a failure, it's just a failure later on.

Answer (score 1):

In A1 write AAA
In B1 write the following:
`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(INDIRECT(A1&"1"))+1),"$",""),"1","")`
and drag it in the same row to C1, D1 till you have the result you need
The formula

- read the cell before it (left column same row) with indirect
- Add 1 to the column
- Substitute $ with ""
- Substitute 1 with ""

Address Function return =Address(1,1) -->$A$1

From [SUPERUSER QUESTION 867965](https://superuser.com/questions/867965/how-to-increment-string-like-aa-to-ab) answered by SeanC